# Нужны ли здесь запятые или запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, причастный-оборот

Все пункты мероприятий в части касающейся руководителей и работников подразделения строго выполняются.

Answer (score 3):

*Все пункты мероприятий в части, **касающейся руководителей и работников подразделения**, строго выполняются.*

Да, запятые нужны, они отделяют с двух сторон причастный оборот, стоящий после определяемого слова (*части*) и находящийся в середине предложения.